# Why did the code run well when I don't close this php echo with a semi-colon but behaves strangely when I do?

Tags: php

I tried to edit this cart form when I click the edit button,

```
<form method="POST" action="cart.php">

<input type="number" name="product_quantity" value="<?php echo $value['product_quantity'] ?>"> <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $value['product_id']; ?>"> <input type="submit" class="edit-btn" name="edit_quantity_btn" value="edit">

</form>
```

but it behaves strangely and did not run correctly when I closed the product_quantity echo with the semi-colon “;” Strangely, it runs very well when I removed it.
Why?
I need to know so I do not spend several frustrating hours looking for the error.
Thank you!

Edit;
Actually the problem is from the statement:

```
else if (isset($_POST['edit_quantity_btn'])){

$product_id = $_POST['product_id']; $product_quantity = $_POST['product_quantity'];

$product = $_SESSION['cart][$product_id];

$product["product_quantity']

$product_quantity;

$_SESSION['cart']['product_id'] = Sproduct;

//calculate total cart

calculateTotalCart();
```

In the cart session, I declared product_id as a string instead of a variable $product_id.
Causing the foreach loop in the form to misbehave. It's fixed now.

Comment: Can you put the error code?

Comment: what exactly is the behaviour you are getting when you insert semi colon? Please elaborate

Comment: Please mention the output you are getting. It's not obvious what strange behavior you are referring to.

Comment: The loop would not affect the first added item, and the edit function doesn't affect the second and third. It was really bizarre lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only working becuse there's explicit PHP closing tag (`?>`) in the code. So if you create test script like this

```php
<?php
echo "foo"
```

then it will fail as expected with

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting "," or ";" in test.php on line 2`.

But if you add `?>` but not `;`:

```php
<?php
echo "foo"
?>
```

then it will work. This behavior is [documented here](https://www.php.net/basic-syntax.instruction-separation):

> The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.

Yet I strongly recommend to develop a habit of always putting `;`.